# Did I insert the links wrong?

Tags: discussion, bug

In my [recent](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/31900/are-there-medications-that-treat-premature-ejaculation-without-interfering-in-se) question, I had added 3 links. But the links didn't go well. The references are visible at the bottom of the question and the link descriptions aren't clickable.

As far as I remember, I didn't do anything wrong. So why did this happen? Is this a bug?

Comment: This is very strange. I attempted to fix it for you, but I can't. I played around with it a while, and there seems to be something about the URLs themselves that the editor doesn't like.  The URLs work fine if I paste them into my browser, but they don't when I make them a link in your question. And it's not the question itself because linking to something like https://www.google.com/ works just fine. I have to go do something else right now but I'll play with it more when I get back.

Comment: @CareyGregory Does the browser I work with have anything to do with it? I'm using Google Chrome for Android.

Comment: No, doesn't work with Chrome or Firefox on Windows either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was a spurious right parentheses in the first URL. See how the URL below no longer looks like a link after the ")" character?

[1]: [https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/in-depth/ssris/art-20044825#:~:text=How%20SSRIs%20work,reuptake](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/in-depth/ssris/art-20044825#:%7E:text=How%20SSRIs%20work,reuptake))%20of%20serotonin%20into%20neurons.

Once I removed that all the links worked. Apparently, a close parentheses without a matching open parentheses confuses the editor.